# MVC controller not getting proper Autofac injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, autofac

I have a .NET MVC site where a user can list their favorite players per sport (baseball, basketball, etc.) I have a Players controller, and I'm injecting IPlayerService. However, my problem is that the service needs to know which sport we're dealing with. I'm currently using keyed parameters with a Sports enum which I'm registering in Autofac like so:

```
foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Sports)))
{
    var sport = (Sports)value;

    builder.RegisterType<PlayerService>()
        .Keyed<IPlayerService>(sport)
        .WithParameter(new NamedParameter("sport", sport))
        .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
}
```

Here is the PlayerService constructor:

```
public PlayerService(Sports sport, IIndex<Sports, IPlayerRepository> repos)
{
    _playerRepo = repos[sport];
    _sport = sport;
}
```

My ultimate question is, how do I register PlayersController so it will properly inject IPlayersService with the correct sport? Assume my route looks like www.example.com/players/baseball.

The Autofac error I'm getting is `None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'PlayerService' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'Sports sport' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Sports, Autofac.Features.Indexed.IIndex'2[Sports,IPlayerRepository])'.`

Comment: What is the constructor of `PlayerService`? Perhaps you just need a slight change: `new NamedParameter("Sports", sport)`

Comment: I updated the question to include the PlayerService constructor.